# Select query with row constructors

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am using RDBMS MySQL 5.7. 
I have two tables with the following structures:

Table A - primary table - products:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
| id | title     | description | createdAt  | status |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Product A | Desc A      | 2019-07-19 |      1 |
|  2 | Product B | Desc B      | 2019-07-04 |      1 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Table B - product_categories -> one-to-many model

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | productId | categoryId |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |          3 |
|  2 |         1 |          5 |
|  3 |         2 |          5 |
|  4 |         2 |          7 |
|  5 |         2 |          9 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

productId and categoryId are foreign keys.

I want to select rows from products table which have categories 3 and 5 both. The query should return the only row with id 1.

I have such a query:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p  
inner join product_categories pc on p.id = pc.productId 
WHERE (pc.productId, pc.categoryId) IN ((p.id, 3), (p.id, 5)) 
GROUP BY productId 
HAVING COUNT(productId) = 2
```

How you would simplify it? Without using row constructors.

Comment: Yes, numbers will be different but the number of values can change. Sometimes can be more,  I will use it as a filter, the number of values can grow as the user selects options. @Akina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select rows from products table which have categories 3 and 5 both.

```
SELECT productId
FROM product_categories
WHERE categoryId IN (3, 5)
GROUP BY productId
-- JOIN products ON products.id = product_categories.productId
HAVING 2 = COUNT(DISTINCT categoryId)
```

If `(productId, categoryId)` is set as unique by index, you may remove DISTINCT.

`products` table not needed at all (except the case when some value of `productId` exists in `product_categories` but not exists in `products`).

> How can I do it with two tables: I have another table similar to product_categories, let's say product_highlights and it has one-to-many relationship as well. How can I query results with values (3, 5) in product_categories and (2, 4) in product_highlights?

```
SELECT t1.productId
FROM product_categories t1
JOIN product_highlights t2 ON t1.productId = t2.productId
WHERE t1.categoryId IN (3, 5)
  AND t2.highlightId IN (2, 4, 6) -- changed to 3 values
GROUP BY productId
-- JOIN products ON products.id = product_categories.productId
HAVING 2*3 = COUNT(DISTINCT categoryId, highlightId)
```

If `(productId, parameterId)` is set as unique by index in BOTH tables, you may remove DISTINCT.

Alternatively you can select `productId` for each table separately in subqueries, then join them in main query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me clarify something. How can I do it with two tables: I have another table similar to product_categories,  let's say  product_highlights and it has one-to-many relationship as well. How can I query results with values (3, 5) in product_categories and (2, 4) in product_highlights?

Comment: @Shahin Code added.

Comment: Thank you @Akina. It is really helpful!